# How is the correct way to add data into the ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I created a function to display the data on my android application uses charts. Data retrieved using the API from my server.

My API result

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "idarchive": "33",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-10",
            "date2": "2016-07-10",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-10 17:32:55",
            "value": "1217"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "74",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-11",
            "date2": "2016-07-11",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-11 17:02:51",
            "value": "1781"
        },
        {
            "idarchive": "90",
            "name": "nb_uniq_visitors",
            "idsite": "1",
            "date1": "2016-07-12",
            "date2": "2016-07-12",
            "period": "1",
            "ts_archived": "2016-07-13 09:18:54",
            "value": "1809"
        }
    ]

}
```

Data taken from the API function properly until the client (android) take it in the form of ArrayList.

Then I add a library to create a chart with sample dummy data
[image: Result]

I'm trying to make the data to be displayed in order to retrieve the data dynamically from server using my API. But how do I change the original sample code

```
int numSubcolumns = 1;
int numColumns = 3;

List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
List<SubcolumnValue> values;

for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; ++i) {

    values = new ArrayList<SubcolumnValue>();
    for (int j = 0; j < numSubcolumns; ++j) {
        int sign = getSign();
        values.add(new SubcolumnValue((float) Math.random() * 20f * sign + 5 * sign, ChartUtils.pickColor()));
    }

    Column column = new Column(values);
    column.setHasLabels(hasLabels);
    column.setHasLabelsOnlyForSelected(hasLabelForSelected);
    columns.add(column);
}

data = new ColumnChartData(columns);

// Set stacked flag.
data.setStacked(true);

if (hasAxes) {
    Axis axisX = new Axis();
    Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
    if (hasAxesNames) {
        axisX.setName("Axis X");
        axisY.setName("Axis Y");
    }
    data.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
    data.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
} else {
    data.setAxisXBottom(null);
    data.setAxisYLeft(null);
}

chart.setColumnChartData(data);
```

Being the result of my API?

I want to replace this section

```
List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
List<SubcolumnValue> values;
```

With my looping data from server

```
for (int x=0; x<listVisitor.size(); x++) {

}
```

Here is my full code when I try to **load data** and **combine** with sample chart code

```
private void load() {

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Retrieving Data", "Please wait...", true);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getVisitor().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<NewVisitorResponse> call = apiService.getVisitor();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<NewVisitorResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewVisitorResponse> call, Response<NewVisitorResponse> response) {

            listVisitor = response.body().getVisitor(); //Dont worry, the data successfully loaded here

            int numSubcolumns = 1;
            int numColumns = listVisitor.size();

            List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
            List<SubcolumnValue> values;

            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; ++i) {

                values = new ArrayList<SubcolumnValue>();
                for (int j = 0; j < numSubcolumns; ++j) {
                    values.add(new SubcolumnValue((listVisitor.get(i).getValue(), ChartUtils.pickColor()));
                }

                for (int x=0; x<listVisitor.size(); x++){
                    Column column = new Column(values);
                    column.setHasLabels(hasLabels);
                    column.setHasLabelsOnlyForSelected(hasLabelForSelected);
                    columns.add(listVisitor.get(i).getDate1());
                }
            }

            data = new ColumnChartData(columns);

            if (hasAxes) {
                Axis axisX = new Axis();
                Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
                if (hasAxesNames) {
                    axisX.setName("Date");
                    axisY.setName("Total Visitor");
                }
                data.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
                data.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
            } else {
                data.setAxisXBottom(null);
                data.setAxisYLeft(null);
            }

            chart.setColumnChartData(data);

            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewVisitorResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "STATUS CODE : " + t.toString());
            Snackbar.make(getView(), "CONNECTION ERROR. PLEASE TRY AGAIN", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Data retrieval is successful, the only problematic on logic placement of data in the chart.

I get error
[image]

I want to add `date1` and `value` field into the chart
Maybe you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to do `columns.add(column)` ? Not sure what the columns list is supposed to contain, but I don't feel like it should be date1s.

Comment: You are trying to add a `String` to a list of `Column`

Comment: Hi @Compass I am confused how to add data into. I learn this way of examples. please correction

Comment: Hi @Naveed Forgive me if I'm confused about this case. I'm new to learn java

Comment: I would recommend starting with a java tutorial first then before jumping into android.  http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java/

Comment: @Naveed Maybe for this time you can help me about that

Comment: I want to add `date1` and `value` field into the chart @Naveed

Comment: It would be hard to answer without seeing the Column class. One thing I can tell you based your current code is what was mentioned before `columns.add(column)`.  Seems like you are already creating the column with those values.  But since I can't see the column class, I can't tell if the column lets you add date or not.

Comment: Hi @Naveed my full fragment class : http://pastebin.com/cExy5aV2

Comment: `load()` function is done with success. In code, you can see `generateDefaultData()` to show dummy data for chart

Comment: I use https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android library